# YouTube playlistItems API returns incomplete result set

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I've seen this issue referred to a few times on here but so far I've not seen any kind of resolution. Am pretty certain this is a bug in the API but any help working around it would be appreciated.

**The problem**: I'm trying to get all of the items in a playlist by using the v3 playlistItems API call. Sometimes it works exactly as expected, but sometimes it comes back with only a partial result set. When it comes back with a partial / incomplete list, two things are always true:

- Only 26 items will be returned. totalResults and resultsPerPage will be correctly set to the full number of items in the playlist, but only 26 items will actually be populated in items []. If a multi-page result set is expected you will receive multiple pages with empty items [] once you get past item # 26.
- This incorrect behaviour is an attribute of the list. If a list displays this behaviour it will apparently always display this behaviour. Some lists always work fine, other lists always seem to truncate at 26 items.

The behaviour is completely independent of maxResults, so if you set maxResults=50 and query a playlists with 50 items in it, the results will say totalResults=50 but you will only actually get 26 items populated.

Whatever the underlying reason for this issue, I feel that if totalResults reports a different number to the actual number of results in the result set it's clearly a bug.

I've seen using the iframe API suggested as a possible solution but I need to de-serialise the results on a background thread in Swift so I'd much prefer to use the v3 data API, providing it worked according to the documentation.

I'm including 3 examples below. You can observe the results by pasting the URL into a browser, after substituting the [key] for your API key.

**Example 1:**

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?key=[key]&playlistId=RDCLAK5uy_kGA_NH_mqT53XwMP_IHL21Pi_bdYBeG58&maxResults=50&part=snippet

pageInfo:
- totalResults : 50
- resultsPerPage : 50

Items returned, page 0:
- Expected : 50
- Got : 26

Total items returned: 26 / 50
```

**Example 2:**

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?key=[key]&playlistId=RDCLAK5uy_mfdqvCAl8wodlx2P2_Ai2gNkiRDAufkkI&maxResults=50&part=snippet

pageInfo:
- totalResults : 81
- resultsPerPage : 50

Items returned, page 0:
- Expected : 50
- Got : 26

Items returned, page 1:
- Expected : 36
- Got : 0

Total items returned: 26 / 81
```

**Example 3:**

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?key=[key]&playlistId=RDCLAK5uy_nUi8B-S9ckz5feHM7oMGyQQ_eKW2Zl9aE&maxResults=50&part=snippet

pageInfo:
- totalResults : 112
- resultsPerPage : 50

Items returned, page 0:
- Expected : 50
- Got : 26

Items returned, page 1:
- Expected : 50
- Got : 0

Items returned, page 2:
- Expected : 12
- Got : 0

Total items returned: 26 / 112
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me on this.

Comment: If the videos are available and the response is intermediate, then, my advice is report in [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/).

Comment: Thanks, I will report the issue.

Comment: But could you be kind to post here on a link to that issue. (Other SO users may find the reference useful.)

Comment: Here’s a link: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/148051135